# How do I modify a caeser cipher program in python to support more characters like space, '$', '&', '%' etc?

Tags: python-3.x, caesar-cipher

I can write a program in python for encrypting and decrypting in Caesar cipher. But I want to modify the program to include more chararcters like space, '$', '&', '%' etc.

the following is the original code

```
def encrypt(text,s): 
    result = "" 

    # traverse text 
    for i in range(len(text)): 
        char = text[i] 

        # Encrypt uppercase characters 
        if (char.isupper()): 
            result += chr((ord(char) - (s-65)) % 26 + 65) 

        # Encrypt lowercase characters 
        else: 
            result += chr((ord(char) - (s - 97)) % 26 + 97) 

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a variant:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

alphabet = ascii_lowercase + '$&%'

def encrypt(plain, key):
    table = str.maketrans(alphabet, key)
    return plain.translate(table)
```

---

[`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.maketrans) will crate a table that can then be used in [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) to map all the characters from the `alphabet` to their shuffled counterparts.
you could then use it as:

```
from random import shuffle

key_list = list(alphabet)
shuffle(key_list)
key = ''.join(key_list)      # kd&ygphtcjxsfwrqo%$zianmvuebl
encrypt('hello world', key)  # tgssr nr%sy
```

your alphabet seems to include uppercase as well; for that just change:

```
from string import ascii_letters
alphabet = ascii_letters + '$&%'
```

note that the `key` needs to have the same length as the `alphabet`.